# Does is it possible access Http context in actor using Java Akka on Play Framework 2.5

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm using JavaAkka to execute some tasks when the Actor receive any message. When my actor receive a message, I'd like to execute some functions from one of the my controllers, however there are inside of these functions uses of http context as:

```
ctx().messages().at("sensor_alert");
```

or

```
session().get("id");
```

And I get the error:

```
[error] 2017-02-02 13:06:54 -0300 a.a.OneForOneStrategy - There is no HTTP Context available from here.
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
    at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:62)
    at play.mvc.Controller.ctx(Controller.java:27)
    at controllers.IpmiMonitorController.gerarAlertas(IpmiMonitorController.java:370)
    at actor.IpmiActor.onReceive(IpmiActor.java:27)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:484)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: What is your use-case to invoke a function from the controller? If you have business functionality, this should go into some other class -- where no http context etc. as it looks, you need some sort of user-specific properties (session, language). which values would you expect if you're calling the controller from the actor? which user would that be? Who triggers the actor message? it it's coming from the controller, you may use the ask pattern and thereby "stay" in the controller for the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP context should go no further than your controller layer, otherwise you'll find yourself with inappropriate coupling.

Additionally, why would you invoke a method on a controller from an actor?  Controllers are meant to handle incoming HTTP requests.  Is it possible this method doesn't belong in a controller?

If you're generating alerts, where are the alerts going to?  If it's the database, inject a DAO into the actor.  If it's going into a HTTP request, inject a web service client or similar into the actor.

Comment: Yes, this could go into another class, but I will need user messages for application internacionalization.

Comment: Inject the messages into the actor, and pass the required language in the message you send to the actor.

Comment: Actually I solved this problem using the play.il8n.MessagesApi instead ctx().messages().at().

Comment: Exactly - inject the messages.  Search the [Play website](https://www.playframework.com) and you should find a list of components the DI setup is already aware of.

Comment: Having a similar problem from the play scheduler. Could you please elaborate on how you injected messages. Thanks.